# sql : How to move full text catalogue

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, full-text-search

I want to move full text catalogue for 1 database to a different location on same SQL server. I am using SQL 2005. One of the source said:

> SQL Server 2005 full-text
>   search provides the ability to easily
>   detach and move full-text catalogs in
>   the same way that SQL Server database
>   files may be detached, moved, and
>   re-attached. Full-text catalogs are
>   included with sp_detach_db and
>   sp_attach_db. After detaching a
>   database, you may move the full-text
>   catalog and/or database data files,
>   and then re-attach the database.
>   Full-text catalog metadata is updated
>   to reflect the change of location.
>   This capability simplifies building,
>   testing, moving, and deploying
>   databases across multiple servers.

From: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345119(SQL.90).aspx

Beleiving it, i only moved data and log file using attach and detach method, copied Full text catalog and rebuild it. Still

```
sp_help_fulltext_catalogs ''
```

shows same output with old path.

Another source:
[http://sqlserverpedia.com/wiki/FTS_-*Restoring*&_Relocating_your_Catalogs](http://sqlserverpedia.com/wiki/FTS_-_Restoring_&_Relocating_your_Catalogs)
mentions Stopping and starting full text search service as a part of move. I can't restart full text service as it is being used by the other databases.

Is there any option using which I can move a single full text catalogue without restarting full text service?

Regards

Manjot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't have to restart service at all..
I just tried it without restarting and it worked as per:
 [http://sqlserverpedia.com/wiki/FTS_-Restoring&_Relocating_your_Catalogs](http://sqlserverpedia.com/wiki/FTS_-_Restoring_%26_Relocating_your_Catalogs)